# It is possible to Communicate Between Flash and JavaScript without embedding

Tags: flash, swfupload

I have found this cool [file-upload repo by mailr](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI)u, it called FileAPI. The FileAPI uses .swf file as debugging tool. How this works without embedding the .swf file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this works without embedding the .swf file??

They seem to be dynamically updating the html page (to now have the SWF embeded). This means using `innerHTML` to generate new content which was **not**  originally coded in the html file. You can check a basic guide **[about innerHTML](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dynamiccontent2.shtml)** here.

Looking at **[FileAPI.js](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/blob/master/dist/FileAPI.js)**, onwards from **[line 3590](https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI/blob/master/dist/FileAPI.js#L3590)** we see they indeed use `innerHTML` to embed a Flash object. It becomes embeded (dynamically) when the right Javascript function is triggered.

Some short snippet of their code is below :

```
/**
 * Publish flash-object
 *
 * @param {HTMLElement} el
 * @param {String} id
 * @param {Object} [opts]
 */
publish: function (el, id, opts){
    opts = opts || {};
    el.innerHTML = _makeFlashHTML({
          id: id
        , src: _getUrl(api.flashUrl, 'r=' + api.version)
        //, src: _getUrl('http://v.demidov.boom.corp.mail.ru/uploaderfileapi/FlashFileAPI.swf?1')
        , wmode: opts.camera ? '' : 'transparent'
        , flashvars: 'callback=' + (opts.onEvent || 'FileAPI.Flash.onEvent')
            + '&flashId='+ id
            + '&storeKey='+ navigator.userAgent.match(/\d/ig).join('') +'_'+ api.version
            + (flash.isReady || (api.pingUrl ? '&ping='+api.pingUrl : ''))
            + '&timeout='+api.flashAbortTimeout
            + (opts.camera ? '&useCamera=' + _getUrl(api.flashWebcamUrl) : '')
            + '&debug='+(api.debug?"1":"")
    }, opts);
},

... etc etc etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

They can use the File API. Don't confuse it with a name of the Mail.ru library. See this links:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#sendAsBinary()